# Points on a line distant from a given point on the line

Tags: slope

I have a line with slope given as the pair: *dx, dy* (slope: *dy/dx*).

Given a point (x, y) on the line, what are the coordinates (x(d), y(d))
of the 2 points such that the distance from (x,y) measured on that line
is equal to *d* (where *d* is any positive value)?

I would like a simple closed-form to be used in a program (to be coded) [better if can avoid trigonometry and use coordinates alone]. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a scaling factor $\alpha$ such that you can traverse your line $d$ units in the direction of the slope $dy/dx=(\alpha dy)/(\alpha dx)$.  The distance $d$ is the hypoteneus:
$$d^2 = (\alpha dx)^2 + (\alpha dy)^2 = \alpha^2 (dx^2 + dy^2) $$
which is clearly $$ \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{dx^2 + dy^2} }$$ as long as the denominator is not $0$ and all numbers are real numbers.

So the points are $(x+\alpha dx, y+\alpha dy)$ and $(x-\alpha dx, y-\alpha dy)$

Comment: You have a typo in $dy^2$

Comment: @EmilioNovati thanks, fixed

Comment: @NazimJ Thank you, great!